# Javascript to create text field with dropdown menu options

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, drop-down-menu, jquery-events

I have been using some Javascript to create a text field once an certain value is selected from a drop-down box, but having a limited knowledge in Javascript now that I need to edit it so that a new dropdown option also creates a text field. When I have tried to edit it seems not not work.
Here is the js I'm an trying to use:

```
$(".claim").change(function() {
    $(".area").find(".field").remove();
    //or
    $('.area').remove('.field');
    if ($(this).val() == "Insurance") {
        $(".area").append("<input class='field' name='cost' type='text' placeholder='Cost' />");

    }
    if ($(this).val() == "Damage &lt;$100") {
        $(".area").append("<input class='field' name='cost' type='text' placeholder='Cost' />");

    }
});
```

and here is the html dropdown box:

```
<div id="area" class="area">

    <strong>Cases:</strong><input name="cases" type=text  placeholder="Cases ID" maxlength="7" style="width:129px;">
    <br />
    <strong>Claim:</strong>
    <select class="claim" id="claim" name="claim"> 
    <option value="">Select a Claim</option>
    <option value="Insurance">Insurance</option>  
    <option value="Warrenty">Warrenty</option>
    <option value="Damage &lt;$100">Damage &lt;$100</option>
    </select>
```

I have attempted to edit the Javascript and a few other things but none seem to work. I am guessing its something that is simple but I am unsure about using Javascript at this moment so any help would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
$(this).val() == "Damage <$100"
```

instead of

```
$(this).val() == "Damage &lt;$100"
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/thecodeparadox/QStkd/177/)**

#### Note

You're comparing string so not need any special character.

#### Some more

Instead of `$(this).val()` use `this.value`, would be faster.

Comment: i have attempeted to use the code u used in the demo and i noticed once i placed it with the rest of my jquery code the Inserance code would would work not the one for damge <100... any idea why this might be

Comment: @Matthew that means above code is not working? is it possible to post your whole jQuery code in fiddle?

Comment: what do u mean make a find replace operation? and yes tis quite a fair bit of code

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/matth4ck3r/p22Y7/ here is the link but for some reason it seems to work once its placed in jsfiddle but on my machine it will not work

Comment: @Matthew It seems your code is just working fine. So where is the issue?

Comment: when its runnning on my xampp client it seems not to work and not do anything so i am confused ?? why it works in jsfiddle i will have to look into it

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12280/discussion-between-thecodeparadox-and-matthew)